# 8 channel async mic recording in matlab

Tags: matlab, asynchronous, audio

I wanted to record a sequence of sounds (using 8 channel mic array).

Matlab's audiorecorder system object does not support more than 2 channels async recording.

When I say async, I want to achieve the following:
The user will press some key (handled by event handler gui) it will start the recording and then again user will press a key then the system will save the current recording and user starts with next audio in the sequence.

I can record 8 ch from Matlab using audioDeviceReader system object but for that, I need to call it for each frame so I will have to create a parallel process that will have to communicate with the event handler and the audioDeviceReader.

I don't have much experience will parallel programming? Should I look into audiorecorder's code and see if can be trivially changed to support 8 ch (If that was the case I think they would have already done it). Or write code to spawn a parallel process which exposes record and stop functions wrapping over audioDeviceReader which can interface with event listener similar to audiorecorder? If so how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Well surprisingly removing the num channel error check in the library code worked. :)